# Swipe to delete also triggers didSelectRowAtIndexPath in iOS7

Tags: ios7, swipe, delete-row

I'm transitioning my iOS6 app to iOS7 and when I swipe to delete a row in my UITableView the swipe also registers as a tap if not released outside the cell to delete.

Anyone got a solution for this?